# CSS styling not loading when using Bulma on webpage

Tags: html, css, json, sass, bulma

I am trying to make a custom Bulma theme, and I followed the tutorial to the point where I have this:

`package.json`

```
{
    "name": "mybulma",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "sass/mystyles.scss",
    "license": "MIT",
    "devDependencies": {
        "bulma": "^0.7.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "css-build": "node-sass --omit-source-map-url sass/mystyles.scss css/mystyles.css",
        "css-watch": "npm run css-build -- --watch",
        "start": "npm run css-watch"
    },
    "overrides": {
        "semver": "^7.5.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "node-sass": "^9.0.0"
    }
}
```

`test.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>My custom Bulma website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="title">
            Bulma
        </h1>

        <p class="subtitle">
            Modern CSS framework based on <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox">Flexbox</a>
        </p>

        <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Input">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <p class="control">
            <span class="select">
                <select>
                <option>Select dropdown</option>
                </select>
            </span>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="buttons">
            <a class="button is-primary">Primary</a>
            <a class="button is-link">Link</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`mystyles.scss`

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import "../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass";
```

This is the result after following all the steps in the tutorial, and attempting to troubleshoot:

[image]

Does someone know how to get the CSS styling to show up? If so, please share your solution.